# QFT's bound states references

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, resource-recommendations, s-matrix-theory, non-perturbative

At a graduate level, QFT courses teach very well how to perform perturbative calculations using LSZ or even the background field method. Plenty of books are suggested to go into the details of this matter, but nobody seems to care about bound states (unless you take a QCD introductory couse, where something is treated). So I wanted to ask if you got some nice textbook or reference which treats QFT bound states in the most comprehensive way you know. Besides, my interest arises as I met some interesting papers about Black Holes as graviton + matter bound states, and in reading them I was simpy lost.

Comment: See perhaps P. Hoyer's *Journey to the Bound States* on [arXiv:2101.06721](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.06721), also published on [SpringerBriefs in Physics (Springer, 2021)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-79489-7).

Comment: See the recent discussion on Peter Woit's blog, https://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=12819